# A problem with import in TypeScript/Electron.js

Tags: javascript, import, electron

I have a file `index.ts`:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
let win

app.on('ready', () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    minHeight: 640,
    minWidth: 480,
    frame:false
  })
  win.loadFile('index.html')
})
```

If I try to run with: `npm start`, I got an error:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1166:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at loadApplicationPackage (D:\VS Projects\Electron App\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:109:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\VS Projects\Electron App\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:155:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1166:10)
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^10.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module"
}
```

How I can solve it?

Comment: Electron will not work with import statements. It uses a Nodejs based environment which doesn't support this syntax. You have to use require instead.

Comment: See the [getting started](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app) page for electron

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm make a mistake! Its not JS, I use Typescript with electron.

Comment: electron doesn't support TypeScript out of the box either. You will have to do additional setup for TypeScript to work.

Comment: And what is that additional setup?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to find a somewhat modern example. [Here](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript) is an example from GitHub on how to use Electron with TypeScript.

Comment: Okay, it's at least something... Thanks, @Chris! You can do this as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use TypeScript with Electron. Electron has types available, however it doesn't directly support executing TypeScript right out of the box. You will need to perform some additional steps to get things working. This goes a bit out of scope of an answer, and would need to be more of a tutorial or example, so I'll provide you with an example from GitHub.

You can view an example of getting started with TypeScript and Electron [Here](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript).

Answer (score 4):

Electron runs through node.js and node.js is behind and uses commonjs import syntax.

To import we do:

```js
const {app} = require("electron");

// equivalent to
//import {app} from 'electron' <- don't use in electron
```

to export we do:

```js
module.exports = app;

// equivalent to
//export default app; <- don't use in electron
```